# Switch loop issues and properly fixing

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, repair

I bought a home w some remodeling done. After being here a little bit, I realize that the front door switch when in the off position it will power a single outlet just below the switch. When I flip the switch on, the outlet dies but the ceiling fan comes on. How sketchy is this and how can this be fixed to where the outlet stays hot and the switch can independently work the fan? Switch loop issues? All the wiring seems to be original. Including pics. [image: front door switch]

[image: outlet below]

[image: outlet below]

Comment: Quite sketchy.  That is a single acting switch, it is on or off, it should not turn off one thing if it turns on a second thing.  Will leave this for the experts.

Comment: How many cables and wires are there in the box behind the switch?    Just the one cable with two wires connected to the switch or are there more?

Answer (score 2):

### That didn't actually work.

The outlet is now *in series* with the ceiling fan. That will semi-work for a very small load like a cell phone charger.  For any larger load, turning on the load will *run the fan* but the load won't work.

This is a dangerous configuration because there's no telling how either load (fan or plug-in) will respond to the low-voltage situation.  For intance most likely the fan will fail to start, and will sit there stalled, overheating its coils.  The first setting on a fan is "HIGH" [for a reason](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hQ3GW7lVBWY).

So this needs to be dismantled and decommissioned.  It was never legal and it never worked.

### So how does one do this properly?

Generally, in any lamp/switch group (e.g. 1 lamp 2 switches), *there is only one place* where "always-hot" and "neutral" are both present.   Those are the two wires you must tap to supply a general-purpose receptacle.  **Common novice blunder: Tapping anywhere else does not work**.  A lot of novices imagine that all locations have useful power for the convenience of novices, but that is wrong.

You can always tap *the lamp*, but there you can only be guaranteed "switched-hot" and "neutral" - so the outlet would only be on with the lamp.

Due to your old-school switch loop, the only viable place to tap is the lamp.  Now on post-NEC 2011 switch loops, it is required to bring always-hot and neutral down to a switch (to power smart switches and motion sensors) - however with cloth wiring you can guess your installation pre-dates NEC 2011.